# How to generate full List and selected Details from XML using XSLT?

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have all the data in XML files, well tagged. The data is of resumes, 1000s of them.
I have to build a front end in Java, in which I will display these resumes in 2 ways:

1. A complete HTML file of all of them.
2. And a complete HTML file of selected ones. For Example: user selects Java, then those resumes having Java will get displayed in HTML format.

I have written XSLT code which displays all  resumes. and now I am quite confused with the another type of display. I Need experts advice. :)

Also will I need 2 separate XSLT for displaying the resumes in 2 ways, as told previously.

***Update:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException, TransformerException 
{
    TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Source xslt = new StreamSource(new File("Resume.xslt"));
    Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslt);

    Source text = new StreamSource(new File("Resume.xml"));
    transformer.transform(text, new StreamResult(new File("ResumeAll.html")));
}
```

The above code is Java code for transforming the XML into HTML using XSLT.

This code will display all the Resumes. Now to display a particular resume or selected resumes, I will have to pass parameters using `setParamaters()` method. Right?

Following is the XSLT sample code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version='1.0' xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'>
<xsl:output method='html' media-type='text/html'/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
 <body>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Resume">
<table align='center' width='800' style="font-family:tahoma; font-size:13pt;">
<tr><td>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </td></tr>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Name">
<table align="center"><tr>
<th style="font-size:24pt; color:navy">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</th>
</tr></table>
</xsl:template>
```

The above Java code and the XSLT file will transform the XML into an HTML file, which will display all the Resumes.

What I should do to display the resumes based on certain condition(s)? Will I need 2 different XSLT files for this? Or only the one which is shown will work with little modifications?

Comment: Is your problem in filtering necessary resumes for displaying? What javax.xml.transform.Source do you use?

Comment: If you show the code you've written for the first display (at least summarize), we can better suggest how to add the 2nd.

Comment: It should be a very small modification to the code you already have working. It's hard to advise on that modification without seeing your existing code, and without knowing why you are finding it difficult.

Comment: @_John: This is an example of how we shouldn't ask a question: too general, no example, as if asking "How to do well in life" -- you will receive many answers each of them as general and useless as the question itself. Please, edit and improve.

Comment: @LarsH-your request has been done.

Comment: @Michael Kay- Yes. added the code.

Comment: @Dimitre- Right said..:)

Comment: IMO you'd be better off taking the resumes, indexing them using Lucene/etc., using that index to search for what you want, and displaying the resumes that match. There is zero *good* reason to use XSLT for anything resembling indexing/searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use as a Source not a StreamSource but SAXSource and implement your own custom filter for it. This SAX-filter should skip tags that you do not want to see in result stream.
E.g.:

```
//...

TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Source xslt = new StreamSource(new File("Resume.xslt"));
Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslt);

SAXParser parser = saxParserFactory.newSAXParser();
XMLSkipResumeFilter reader = new XMLSkipResumeFilter(parser.getXMLReader(), resumeIdsToLeave);
InputStream is = new FileInputStream("Resume.xml");
Source text = new SAXSource(filter, is);

transformer.transform(text, new StreamResult(new File("ResumeAll.html")));

//...
```

XMLSkipResumeFilter.java:

```
public class XMLSkipResumeFilter extends XMLFilterImpl {
    private boolean skipCurrentTag = false;
    private Set resumeIdsToLeave;

    public XMLSkipResumeFilter(XMLReader parent, Set resumeIdsToLeave) {
        super(parent);

        this.resumeIdsToLeave = resumeIdsToLeave;
    }

    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes atts) throws SAXException {
        // analyze if current tag should be skipped or check if parent tag is already marked as skipped
        // if (...) { return; }
        // if this resume should be rendered calling to super method
        // if (...) { super.startElement(uri, localName, qName, atts); }
    }

    //implements other method of XMLFilterImpl
}
```

Comment: @svaor- I will give it a try and will let you know about the same